# Height of tables in pdfmake

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdfkit, pdfmake

How do I prevent the content of the tables from altering the height of the tables?

```
{
        style: 'tableExample',
        table: {
            heights: [20, 20, 20],
            body: [
                ['lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem', 'column B'],
                ['lorem lorem lorem', 'column B'],
                ['lorem lorem lorem', 'column B']
            ]
        }
    }
```

The first row exceeds 20 points.
I don't want it to self-adjust

Comment: I don't believe this is possible in the current version. If you just want the text to cut off instead of extend the line you may need to format the string appropriately (e.g. a max character limit) before passing it into the PDFmake structure.

Comment: One way might be to use `maxHeight` & `noWrap` fields to get clipping. see also: https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/264

Answer (score 0):

You can set it like this, or you can create your own custom layout as described in their documentation [here](https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/0.1/document-definition-object/tables/)

```
{
        style: 'tableExample',
        table: {
            heights: 20,
            body: [
                ['lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem', 'column B'],
                ['lorem lorem lorem', 'column B'],
                ['lorem lorem lorem', 'column B']
            ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: Setting `heights` to a single value or to an array of same value is equivalent. Layouts enable you to define borders and paddings and such. They don't deal with row heights directly.